# Spring Boot how can i customize BadRequestException

Tags: spring-boot, controller, spring-restcontroller

I have created a BadRequestException class and I want to show this when the controller returned 400 errors. But I couldn't make this.

My controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PostDto> getPostById(@PathVariable Long id) {
          if(!(id instanceof Long))
               throw new BadRequestException("your request is not valid !");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(restTemplateService.getPostById(id));
    }
```

My General Exception Handler:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GeneralExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  @NotNull HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                  @NotNull HttpStatus status,
                                                                  @NotNull WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach(error -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });

        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(PostNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> postNotFoundExceptionHandler(PostNotFoundException exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> badRequestExceptionHandler(BadRequestException exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

BadRequestException class:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work just fine. What is not working? Can you provide more details?

Comment: `if(!(id instanceof Long))` this condition will never be true, If the parameter is not of type Long, `getPostById()` will never get called.